# Creating components as static factory style (Singleton) in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to create custom [Window](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html) using static factory style (or with singleton pattern).

```
public class MyWindow extends CustomComponent {
private static Window window;
private static MyWindow instance;

public static MyWindow getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyWindow();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void show() {
    UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
}

private MyWindow() {
    CustomLayout layout = new CustomLayout("My HTML Layout");
    window = new Window("My Window");
    window.center();
    window.setWidth("615px");
    window.setModal(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setClosable(true);
    window.setContent(layout);
}
}
```

And call as `MyWindow.getInstance().show();` First time calling was ok but after closing this window and while reopened , I got below error logs at my console.

```
Jul 23, 2014 3:42:39 AM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.vaadin.ui.Window already has a parent.
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.setParent(AbstractComponent.java:469)
at com.vaadin.ui.Window.setParent(Window.java:155)
at com.vaadin.ui.UI.attachWindow(UI.java:501)
at com.vaadin.ui.UI.addWindow(UI.java:490)
```

So , how can I use customize [Windows](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html) with static factory style and how to hide and show [Windows](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html) ?

Comment: You should not create a static Window (or any other component) in Vaadin. Because it means that the same instance will be shared by all users of the application and that's wrong.

Just remove the singleton pattern and the problem is fixed (and also future problems when you have multiple users for the application.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create a new Window Object everytime you call the show() method.

Comment: This kind of answers to the problem which is actually the singleton pattern. One should never create singleton Windows (or other components) in Vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your Window already have a parent. It means that it wasn't removed when you closed it. It is actually weird I've never had that error before. But you can try this if you want:

```
 window.addCloseListener(new CloseListener() {

  @Override
  public void windowClose(CloseEvent e) {
    AbstractSingleComponentContainer.removeFromParent(subwindow);
  }
});
```

This should resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes , It works for me . Thanks . BTW , If remove window from parent , will window instance be null ?

Comment: No the window will still be there but not visible because it is not added inside a container in you page.

Comment: I downvoted because the actual problem in the question is the singleton pattern.