# Custom Listeners with detach() method error

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to know about [Vaadin's detach() method](https://vaadin.com/api/7.1.0/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#detach%28%29). How can I understand below definition from API ?

> ***Called before the UI is removed from the session.***

I got a problem when creating custom listener such as [BroadCaster](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Broadcasting+messages+to+other+users) .

**MyCustomListener.java**

```
public interface MyCustomListener {
void fireEvent(MyCustomEvent event);
}
```

**MyCustomEvent.java**

```
public class MyCustomEvent {
private String message;

public MyCustomEvent(final String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public final String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
}
```

**MyCustomDispatcher.java**

```
public final class MyCustomDispatcher {
private static LinkedList<MyCustomListener> customListeners = new LinkedList<MyCustomListener>();
private static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

private MyCustomDispatcher() {

}

public static synchronized void register(final MyCustomListener listener) {
    customListeners.add(listener);
}

public static synchronized void unregister(final MyCustomListener listener) {
    customListeners.remove(listener);
}

public static synchronized void invokeMyCustomEvent(final String message) {
    if (message == null || message.trim().length() <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    for (final MyCustomListener listener : customListeners) {
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                listener.fireEvent(new MyCustomEvent(message));
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

I call this listener from my UI class as ...

```
public class HelloWorldUI extends UI implements MyCustomListener {

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Getting initialized !");
    MyCustomDispatcher.register(this);
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);
    setSizeFull();
    layout.addComponent(new Label("Hello World !"));
}

@Override
public void detach() {
    System.out.println("Listener was Unregister !");
    MyCustomDispatcher.unregister(this);
    super.detach();
}

@Override
public void fireEvent(MyCustomEvent event) {
    // Do Something
}
}
```

I call *unregister()* method of my custom listener inside `detach()` method for

1. from some examples for custom listener
2. to avoid receiving messages for UIs no longer in use (and ensuring that the detached UI can be garbage collected).
3. [Cleaning up resources in a UI](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Cleaning+up+resources+in+an+UI)

My problem was due to `detach()` method because when I refreshed my browser , my listener instance was deleted (*from detach() method*). So , I can't get `fireEvent()` anymore. I debugged , `detach()` method was called after `init()` method of my UI when refreshing browser. But if I remove calling `unregister(MyCustomListener listener)` from `detach()` method , that may cause nesting events (*previous listeners were still alive*).

What am I wrong ? How can I fix it ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: At least I don't understand what's your problem exactly. Could you explain it better? Thanks!

Comment: @HenriKerola My problem was ***my listener instance was deleted by my `detach()` method when browser refreshed.*** I call `unregister()` from `detach()` method due to above 3 facts. I am sure if I don't refresh browser, my program was ok.

Comment: Refreshing creates a new UI instance for the tab. Is that the behaviour you are seeing? The old instance will be detached but not immediately..

Comment: @HenriKerola Sir ! I have opened for it with [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009160/does-detach-method-call-after-attach-method) . Please explain me more what is `... the old instance will be detached but not immediately` ?

Comment: Note that you may not always see your `detach` method called. See [this forum posting](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/1409950) by Henri Sara.

Comment: @Cataclysm You may be interested in this [fully-working example I built](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872769/642706) for this other question, [Displaying Same Data Across Multiple Clients Using Push in Vaadin 7 app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27872756/642706). Instead of trapping for `detach`, I use an event bus ([MBassador](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador)) to hold [weak references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) to the widgets/layouts interested in fresh data events being published via Push.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry ! this is stupid question . Vaadin's component were server-side codes and I should avoid using ***static*** as I much as I can. When I am using my custom listeners as ***static-resources*** , these events were share all others. If someone invokes one event , every users will get same.

Static collection of listeners (sharing events) may only suitable for [server-push](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html).

I shouldn't create custom listeners as like this.
Thanks @HenriKerola for explanation of [using static fields in vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881151/creating-components-as-static-factory-style-singleton-in-vaadin#comment-38678757) and about the [creating new UI instance when browser was refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009160/does-detach-method-call-after-attach-method#answer-25009285).

Comment: Not stupid at all. Programming web apps in a highly-threaded [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) environment is confusing and tricky work. I'm sure this Question and the related ones will be quite helpful to other folks.