# Does detach() method call after attach() method?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a simple UI class

```
public class HelloWorldUI extends UI {

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Initialized !");
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.addComponent(new Label("Hello World !"));
    setContent(layout);
}

@Override
public void detach() {
    System.out.println("Detach !");
    super.detach();
}

@Override
public void attach() {
    System.out.println("Attach !");
    super.attach();
}
}
```

When first time my UI was loaded , I see outputs at my console as

> Attach !
>   Initialized !

It is OK and this is what I expected. But when I refresh the browser , my console outputs were

> Attach !
>   Initialized !
>   Detach !

Amazing ! I think `Detach !` may be produce first because (*as I think)* when browser was refreshed , `detach()` method should be call and `attach()` , `init()` should be follow . But actually `detach()` method will call after `attach()` method. What's wrong my thinking ?

Comment: The [accepted answer is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25009285/642706). I just want to note that the **`detach` method is not always called** in every situation. See [this forum posting](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/1409950) by Henri Sara. So you should not depend on this as an avenue to clean up resources, close connections, stop background threads, and such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Browser Refresh = New `UI` Instance

When you refresh a browser window or tab, a new [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html) instance is created. So you see an attach message of a *new* `UI` instance. The old `UI` instance will be detached later.

This is default behavior in Vaadin 7. You may change that behavior with an annotation.

## @PreserveOnRefresh

Adding [@PreserveOnRefresh](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/annotations/PreserveOnRefresh.html) annotation to the `UI` changes the behavior: No new `UI` instance won't be created on refresh.

To quote the doc for this annotation:

> Marks a UI that should be retained when the user refreshed the browser window. By default, a new UI instance is created when refreshing, causing any UI state not captured in the URL or the URI fragment to get discarded. By adding this annotation to a UI class, the framework will instead reuse the current UI instance when a reload is detected.

Comment: Is `@PreserveOnRefresh` annotation always need in every UI ? Which conditions shouldn't use `@PreserveOnRefresh` ? I think it is very useful ***no new UI instance won't be created on refresh*** .

Comment: It is an annotation so if you add it, it will be in use for every instance of UI. If you actually want that a refesh doesn't create a new UI instance, then always use the annotations. Some projects prefer it that way, others prefer a new UI.

Comment: To clarify, a Vaadin 7 app can have more than one [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html) class. At least one UI is required, as it defines the content for the first browser window/tab (or Portlet view area). You may choose to [open additional windows/tabs](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.html) in which the same or a different `UI` will be displayed. Presumably you could mark one UI class with the annotation while leaving another UI unannotated, with each having different behavior. Caveats: (a) I've not tried this to verify. (b) Differing behavior be confusing to the user.